# How to select top row from spark sql join

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I have 2 dataframes like this.
df1

```
+----+-------------+
|colA|colB         |
+----+-------------+
|   1|   "someval" | 
|   2|   "someval2"|  
|   3|   "someval3"|
```

df2

```
+----+-------------+
|colA|colC         |
+----+-------------+
|   1|   "someval" | 
|   1|   "someval2"|  
|   2|   "someval3"|
```

if I do inner join df1 and df2 (via colA) I get this .

```
+----+-------------+----------+
|colA|colB         |colC      |
+----+-------------+----------+
|   1|   "someval" |"someval" |
|   1|   "someval" |"someval2"| 
|   2|   "someval2"|"someval3"|
```

But I want only the distinct row of colA (So, fetching the top row of colA will suffice)

```
+----+-------------+----------+
|colA|colB         |colC      |
+----+-------------+----------+
|   1|   "someval" |"someval" |
|   2|   "someval2"|"someval3"|
```

Comment: in the answer given below df2.select('colA').distinct() , will not work because I need to display all 3 cols. I tried out dropDuplicates function(which I was not aware of) and it worked. so If you can edit the answer to use dropDuplicates only , then I will accept the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
distinct_df = df2.dropDuplicates(['colA'])
```

Joining your dataframes

```
inner_join_df = df1.join(distinct_df, df1.colA == distinct_df.colA)
inner_join_df.show()
```

I have joined dataframes using pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
data1 =[[1,'someval'],[2,'someval2'],[3,'someval3']]
data2 =[[1,'someval'],[1,'someval2'],[2,'someval3']]

df1=pd.DataFrame(data1,columns=['colA','colB'])
df2=pd.DataFrame(data2,columns=['colA','colC'])

unique_df=df2.drop_duplicates('colA')

joindf = pd.merge(df1,unique_df,on='colA',how='inner')
print(joindf )
```

Answer (score 0):

use window function to sort rows with same value of column A as you prefer using other columns .In second step filter only rows with function result 1

`sqlContext.sql("""
select colA,colB,colC from (
SELECT   *,row_number() over (PARTITION  by colA order by colB,colC) as rn  from df_p )x where rn=1  """
              ).show(60)`